# Instances of tick damage after being knocked down?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

How is the tick damage applied to you when you are knocked down? Is it relative to circle or the amount of damage received (from any source) before getting knocked out?

Comment: It isn't very clear what are you meaning. What damage? From circle? From players? What is "instances of damage"? Is it a circle damage ticks? Why exactly after being knocked out? There is no difference.

Comment: You slowly begin to tick down after getting knocked out. I will edit my question

Comment: I haven't played much squads but I always assumed that the gradual health decline when you're knocked is the same all the time.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It is not, not sure the exact amounts but it appears to increase each time you are knocked down and revived

Comment: @Malco Ah I mainly play solo so probs why, don't think I've been knocked more than once too haha

Answer (score 2):

**Summary of Tick Damage**

- The tick damage you received is a set pre-determined amount.
- The damage you receive just before being knocked down does not affect the tick damage you take while downed.
- You may receive other damage in addition to the passive tick damage from being knocked down (i.e. Blue zone, being shot, etc).
- Being in the blue zone while knocked out may make it appear that you are taking more tick damage from being knocked out but this is just because you're taking the passive tick damage from being knocked out plus the passive tick damage from being in the blue zone.
- Being knocked down multiple times will cause subsequent knockdowns to deal more tick damage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been knocked down previously, the blue zone will deal more damage. I just tested and I could barely heal from bandages on phase 3 with full energy and ended up dead, of course, while my teammate was chilling with almost full HP, not even using bandages, but also with full energy. The ticks on me were double the damage that he was taking.

Comment: Good to know! I had no idea.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Certainly the patch that introduced this mechanic would be listed in the patch notes.  As far as I remember, this isn't how the blue zone works.  If you get knocked down once, the next time you get knocked down you will bleed out faster, but that is only when you are knocked down.  The amount the Blue zone damages you is dependent on what phase the blue zone is in.